# Dynamic Fields Added at runtime disappears on page reload

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, mysql

I had made a form that contains predefined fields and page have a side nav bar where different dynamic field options are there like Add Question, Add Textarea, Add Number, etc. I had made this dynamic fields with javascript onclick function. My problem is on page reload dynamic fields disappear. How to save dynamically added form fields? Please provide me some hints or suggestions as I am a beginner in dynamic form.

Comment: you can take hidden field and store value of how many dynamic field you have created on...!! and you can store it backend when page load you can load value in hidden field and  `onpage load` event you can load all dynamic elements. 
if you want to store it front.. then please store it into javascript object

Comment: @DevangHingu  Thanks for your response, can you please provide me an example.

Comment: Please share your code on jsFiddle so I can understand situation batter

Answer (score 0):

you can use Session.storage to control them ...

and check it on page reload

if(user_was_open_this_before) showdynamicfield()

Comment: Thank You! Can you please provide me some examples so I can understand better.